# NSDateFormater +0000

Tags: xcode, nsdate

Hey  I'm having problems formatting my date ....

my code it this :

```
 NSString *dateString = news.date;
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 dateFormatter.DateFormat =@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";

 NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

 dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateString];


 NSLog(@" %@", dateFromString);
```

if i look at my dateString  it´s 2012-03-06T12:15:45
but when i format it, it comes out  2012-03-06 11:15:45 +0000

how do i remove the +0000  ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dateFromString` is an `NSDate` instance. So `2012-03-06 11:15:45 +0000` is the correct result you get when you call `NSLog(@" %@", dateFromString);`. That's simply how the method `description` of `NSDate` works.

If you want to change a string of type `2012-03-06T12:15:45` to a string of type `2012-03-06 11:15:45, then you have to create another string from`dateFromString` like the following:

```
// ...
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
NSLog(@"%@", newDateString);
```